# Implementing many_to_many relation with checkboxes

Tags: php, yii, many-to-many

I've gotten stuck on something that I believe is down to my in-experience with the many to many relationship.

In my application I am mapping interests to products with a many to many. I wish to create the following scenario whereby the full list of interests is listed under a specific product with check boxes. For every check box that is selected when the form is submitted, a row is added to the InterestProductAssignment table.

In my product controller I call the full list of interests-

```
$interests = Interest::model()->findAll();
```

Actually I don't get a lot further than this as my mind is in knots wondering where to proceed from here. What I've tried so far is building an array of InterestProductAssignment objects to match the interests array I've returned above. I've tried passing it to the view and building out the form, but I've gotten myself fairly confused by trying to match the two up and I can't believe I'm using Yii correctly as it's messy.

Is anyone able to outline a solution for this problem that enables me to have a checkbox against every interest that would add a link between the product and interest upon submitting? I'd be interested to see what you'd write in the controller and view.

Just to clarify, this page is the subject of just one product.

**EXTENSION**

For the supplementary problem I'm having, I'm posting the code I've got, this may also help others implement a similar thing, once we find the mistake.

**My relation within my product controller reads like this-**

```
            'interests'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Interest', 'interest_product_assignment(interest_id, product_id)')
```

**Controller**

```
    public function actionUpdate($id)
{
            // loadModel as been adapted to be called "->with('interests')"
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Product']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Product'];
        if($model->save())
            foreach($_POST['ProductInterest'] as $i => $interest_id){
                $this_interest = new InterestProductAssignment;
                $this_interest->product_id = $model->id;
                $this_interest->interest_id = $interest_id;
                $this_interest->save();
            }
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

**Relevant part of view _form.php**

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo CHtml::checkBoxList('ProductInterest', CHtml::listData($model->interests, 'interest_id', true), CHtml::listData(Interest::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'interest'));?>
</div>
```

The problem is that the second field in checkBoxList does not seem to properly fill in the check boxes that are already selected. I suspect that the root cause of this is likely a daft mistake. I can't spot it though and I'm not familiar enough with checkBoxList.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goose,

I think what you are looking for here is the [CheckBoxList](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#checkBoxList-detail).

In your form you can use the code

```
echo CHtml::checkBoxList('Product_Interests', $model->getInterests(), CHtml::listData(Interest::model()->findAll(), 'interest_id', 'interest_title'));
//$model->getInterests() is a method that should returns an array of IDs of all the currently selected interests
```

Then in your controller you can use the code:

```
foreach($_POST['Product_Interests'] as $interest_id=>$checked)
    if($checked)
      $model->addInterest($interest_id); //Add Interest
    else
      $model->removeInterest($interest_id); //Remove an Interest if it exists
//Note: If you have a model that connects these tables those can be created or destroyed here
```

Comment: Thanks again Zane, this is what I've been looking for. I have one question though. I'm having trouble filling the second argument. If I have the product ID how do I use the many_many relation to populate the array of already selected interests?

Comment: The easiest way (that I know of) if to just create a key=>value array with the key being the key of the Interest and the value being true or false (if it is selected/already an interest) Try: `CHtml::listData($model->ProductInterests, "interest_id", true)`

Comment: I'm not sure how to construct this with a many_many relationship. If you have any pointers please let me know. Else I think I will post it as a separate question as I've still not made any progress on this last bit.

Comment: @goose In your `relations` method add the line `'interests' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Interest', 'interests_in_product(product_id, interest_id)')` where the last option is the table the connects the products and interests table and the primary keys listed in that table. You should then be able to call it from the Product model as `$model->interests`. [More Reading](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-options)

Comment: Thanks again for your time on this Zane. I do have something similar setup in my relations, I'll give it further scrutiny soon. One thing comes to mind, in your earlier comment you state to write this in the view file- CHtml::listData($model->ProductInterests, "interest_id", true). In my database I have not represented anything with strings true/false etc. instead 0s and 1s in an integer type column. Could this be the issue?

Comment: The reason the code above should work is that the only models that would be under the relation are the ones that are connected the Product model. The `true` in this case only refers to the fact the the column should be selected, and the should select only Interests that are already applied to the Product. If you could post a diagram of the related DB tables it may be helpful in seeing where the issue is.

Comment: Hi Zane, I can't figure this out. I've posted the code as you suggest. Let me know if there's anything more you might want to see, but I think I've got all the relevant parts on there.

Comment: I've narrowed this down. The problem doesn't seem to be in the implementation of checkBoxList, I think the relation isn't setup correctly as it is returning an empty array.

Comment: As far as I can see that relation looks correct. If the relation was not setup correctly Yii would likely complain about it, and as you have it looks correct. You should check your database (in something such as PHPMyAdmin or the MySQL Workbench) to make sure values are being inserted in your bridge table. If that table is empty, it would make sense that your array is also empty.

Comment: Thanks Zane, I've finally got this last bit solve now. A couple of things were at the root cause, none it turns out related to checkBoxList, but poor knowledge of many_many. First I think my keys were input the wrong way -  'interests_in_product(interest_id, product_id)' - I think this made a difference. Also, I neglected to put a primary key into my bridge table (I think this made a difference).

Comment: I'd also note, from what I was able to determine, the array returned by checkBoxList only returns those values that were selected. So I had to loop through the list of all possible interests and cross reference it with the values that were checked, saving/deleting as needed. Despite all of that though, you pointed me straight to the answer, most of the above are my mistakes/ignorance. Glad this is fixed though! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: To fix the problem of looping check out the `uncheckValue` special HTML attributes of checkbox list. It will let you set Yii what value (if any) to set for boxes that are not checked.

Comment: Thanks Zane, I have a feeling this will significantly simplify my code. Which is much needed!

Comment: Hi Zane, I had a little more trouble with this, but didn't want to keep on the same question. I've posted it here if you're interested- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256442/checkboxlist-uncheckvalue-adds-two-values-to-returned-array-yii